# Javascript window.addEventListener() fails to trigger after calling a jQuery .load() command to a new PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, addeventlistener

I currently have a PHP based website with a mix of Javascript & jQuery. On this page, I have buttons to load a new page through a jQuery script that refreshes a div. This is so that only a portion of my page refreshes instead of the entire page, as this avoids reloading a series of other code that takes longer to load yet wouldn't need to be refreshed when navigating through my website.

On the 1st page, I have a `window.addEventListener("load")` that updates once the page fully loads. However, when I load the next page through my jQuery script, `window.addEventListener("load")` doesn't trigger.

I fully understand why this fails, since I'm technically only refreshing a portion of the page instead of the entire document. However, what sort of replacement would be needed for page2.php's `window.addEventListener("load")`?

Below is my code, thanks

**page1.php**

```
<!-- page1.php -->
<script>
     function NewPage(userID, page) {
          $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#tabcontent").load("page2.php", {
                    userID: userID,
                    page: page
               });
          });
     }
<script>
<?php
     echo '<div id="tabcontent">
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<key>"))

            try {
                web3.eth.getBalance("'.$addrHash.'", function (err, result) {
                    if (result) {
                        document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML = web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
                    }
                })
            } catch (err) {
                document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML = "-";
            } 
        })
    </script>
    <span style="font-weight:bold" id="'.$id.'"></span>';

    <button onclick="NewPage(`'.$userID.'`, `.($page-1).`)">Previous Page</button>              
    <button onclick="NewPage(`'.$userID.'`, `.($page+1).`)">Next Page</button>
</div>';
?>
```

**page2.php**

```
<!-- page2.php -->
<?php
     $userID = $_POST['userID'];
     $page = $_POST['page'];

     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<key>"))

            try {
                web3.eth.getBalance("'.$addrHash.'", function (err, result) {
                    if (result) {
                        document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML = web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
                    }
                })
            } catch (err) {
                document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML = "-";
            } 
        })
    </script>
    <span style="font-weight:bold" id="'.$id.'"></span>';
          
     <button onclick="NewPage(`'.$userID.'`, `.($page-1).`)">Previous Page</button>              
     <button onclick="NewPage(`'.$userID.'`, `.($page+1).`)">Next Page</button>';
?>
```

Comment: Does the jQuery API documentation for the [`complete`](https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) parameter of a `load` request answer your question?

Comment: @traktor, not at all. I've looked through that documentation and the addEventListener for months. Moved onto other tasks for this site and revisited it today. I am completely stumped & just now asked the StackOverFlow community after a few months later

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the on load event?

from your code I feel like you just want to add some pagination logic, so can't you just use the event from the Next Page, Prev Page on click?

or maybe if you want, you can trigger a custom event that represent "a page change"

Comment: I'm using the load event today to do exactly as what's stated in my original message, load new pages but only within a div (refreshing the div) versus loading a brand new page. What I provided was a partial piece of my code for this example, as I have much more pulling lengthy SQL query requests that don't need to be reloaded upon every new page load.

The .load command passes the userID and page arguments to page2.php, where those are then retrieved via POSTs where the page is then updated with a new page of information. The main prob is I don't know how to edit 'addEventListener' on page2

Comment: "I'm using the load event today to do exactly as what's stated.in my original message, load new pages but only within a div (refreshing the div) versus loading a brand new page" -> isn't this "what you do using the load **function**"? I'm asking what you do you want to do using the on load **event**

Comment: I want the window.addEventListener() function on page2.php to work and be able to read the rest of my code in that function. So far it's not triggering and none of the code inside is exectued, even with the "load" paramenter, and have no idea what event to set a trigger for the code to work. I ran debugging within Chrome and saw the "load" event is triggered whenever I refresh my page, but then nothing is triggered when I click on a new page with my button that refrences the jQuery function that runs .load refreshing the div

Comment: yes I understand that you want the `addEventListener` function to work, and be able to read the rest of your code inside the function. And yes it won't be triggered as you said in the question, because the load function and the on load event is not the same thing (at least to my understanding). But what exactly do you want to do in the `addEventListener` function inside it, because depending on your answer, I can't really know what you need to do. For example, if you just want to do something about pagination, just put what you need to do in the on click event of the Next Page/Prev Page button

Comment: Hey @RonaldoC Im using a window.addEventListener to show web3 data:

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<key>"))

  try {
  web3.eth.getBalance("'.$addrHash.'", function (err, result) {
   if (result) {
    document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML = web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether");
   }
  })
  } catch (err) {
   document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML = "-";
  } 
 })
</script>
<span style="font-weight:bold" id="'.$id.'"></span>';

Comment: There is probably an easier method of just doing everything in React, but that would set back the release of my site for months. Right now I'm looking to integrate that Javascript code into PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery is already being used, you should use the [jQuery AJAX functionality](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to asynchronously load a portion of the page (this is not a page-load event - there is only one per page request).

I have attempted to simplify the code and organize it a little so that you may get rid of some of the PHP/HTML throughout the page an limit it to the beginning. Also, there is an `always` method to use if you wish, similar to a `finally` block in Java. This can be read about in the documentation link provided.

```
<script>
    /**
     * create JS vars for the user and current page.
     */
    var userID = <?=$userID?>;    
    var curPage = <?=$page?>;    
   
    //-replaced ready event handler with short-hand.    
    $(function(e){
        $("#tabcontent").load("page2.php", {
            userID: userID,
                    page: page                  
                }, function(e){
                        console.log('page2.php loaded.'); //<--new code here.
                });
            });
    });

    /** 
     * Create function to handle next content loading.
     */
    function nextPage(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'page2.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: '{"userID":userID,"page":}'
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){       

                /** Just for debugging to see what you have to utilize. Remove for production. */
                console.log(data);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                /** end debugging. */

                /** Load retrieved HTML into tab. */
                $('#tabcontent').html(data);

            }).fail(function(jqXHR, txtStatus, errorThrown){
                /** display friendly error to user. */
                $('#tabcontent').html('There has been an error. Please contact ......'));
                
                /** show error message to console and any additional params jQuery provides to figure out issue. */
                console.error("Error loading page2: " + txtStatus);
            });
        });
        };
        </script>
        <button onclick="nextPage(<?=$page--?>)">Prev</button>
        <button onclick="nextPage(<?=$page++?>)">Next</button>            
    </div>';
</script>

<div id="tabcontent">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey brw, thanks for the response. I added to my original code the specific window calls being made (web3.window), and the above doesn't work

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving and also what versionof jQuery you are using.

Comment: I have edited my answer since you provided some additional details. See how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks brw, this works. Evidently the better longterm solution for me is redoing everything on Node / React